# script.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: att is not defined

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am very new to javascript and is trying to consume the api I made and encountered an error here is the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: att is not defined
    at script.js:24
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at script.js:10
```

here is my javascript:

```
function getData(){

fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/read')
.then((res)=> {
    return res.json();
})
.then((data)=> {
    let result = `<h2> User Info From sampleUser.json </h2>`;
    data.forEach((booking) => {
        const { bookingId, bookingDesc, bookedUser, bookedUserName, bookedEmail, 
            bookingCode, dateBooked, startTime, endTime, att: {attendeesEmail} } = booking
        result +=
        `<div>
            <h5> User ID: ${bookingId} </h5>
            <ul class="w3-ul">
                <li> Booking Description : ${bookingDesc}</li>
                <li> User: ${bookedUser} </li>
                <li> Username : ${bookedUserName}</li>
                <li> User Email: ${bookedEmail} </li>
                <li> Date Booked: ${dateBooked} </li>
                <li> Start time : ${startTime}</li>
                <li> End time: ${endTime} </li>
                <li> Attendees Email: ${att[0]["attendeesEmail"]} </li>
            </ul>
        </div>`;

        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
    });
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `att: {attendeesEmail}` to `att: attendeesEmail` for it to resolve correctly. This is called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and is done by matching key names.

Comment: It worked but the result is Attendees Email: [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: I changed     this            <li> Attendees Email: ${att[0]["attendeesEmail"]} </li> to this                 <li> Attendees Email: ${attendeesEmail} </li>